# Editing the Latex source of equations in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, latex

I noticed that Google Docs now allows putting equations in documents. Is there any way to view/edit the Latex source for these equations?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible to edit the inserted equations with LaTeX, but there're addons that let you write LaTeX and insert it as equation to Google Docs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to edit the source of LaTex in Google Docs, and there is no official documentation about the Google Docs client-side code.

The way to extend Google Docs is by using Google Apps Script and Google Docs API, and none of them include methods to change the source of LaTex to be used in Google Docs.

Anything done on the client side (user styles, scripts, file mapping, etc.) can fail inexpectively due to changes that Google might silently push as they regularly do. Still, it might be possible to find from time to time web browser extensions, open source projects and scripts that take the risk of extending certain Google Docs features.

Only install software from trusted developers and use code that you really understand what it does and the permissions that it requires to run.

References

- https://developers.google.com/docs/
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs
- https://developers.google.com/docs/api